# Does IIS support CEA-608 closed captions transformation?

Tags: ios, silverlight, iis, http-live-streaming, smooth-streaming

I use IIS Smooth Streaming (.isml) stuff to deliver video stream to Silverlight plugin and to IOS devices by IIS HLS re-encoding "on fly". Also I send "Closed Captions" to live stream - it works fine on Silverlight plugin but HLS stream doesn`t display Closed Captions.
Is it possible that IIS forgets about text stream in source .isml stream?

Playlist example

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=581120,RESOLUTION=276x208
QualityLevels(560000)/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=781432,RESOLUTION=364x272
QualityLevels(756000)/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1078834,RESOLUTION=480x360
QualityLevels(1047000)/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=167920
QualityLevels(160000)/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl).m3u8

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:1
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=0,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:11,no-desc
Fragments(Video=100000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=200000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=300000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=400000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:11,no-desc
Fragments(Video=600000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=700000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=800000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=900000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=1000000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=1200000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:11,no-desc
Fragments(Video=1300000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=1400000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:7,no-desc
Fragments(Video=1500000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I think now the question is "Does IIS support CEA-608 closed captions transformation?"

Comment: Can you post the contents of one of the resulting live HLS master playlists?

Comment: #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:1
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=0,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:11,no-desc
Fragments(Video=100000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=200000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=300000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=400000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:11,no-desc
Fragments(Video=600000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXTINF:12,no-desc
Fragments(Video=700000000,format=m3u8-aapl).ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

Comment: There are no **WebVTT** closed captions present in the master playlist so you'll have to check if IIS Live Smooth Streaming supports **CEA-608** closed captions embedded in the MPEG Transport Stream. I'm not familiar with IIS so maybe someone else can give a definitive answer.

Comment: Can you show me an example of playlist with WebVTT?

Comment: [Adding Closed Captions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW23) [developer.apple.com]